How to change the search engine Icon?
I have a website and have now published it. The problem is that it still shows the React icon from the sample in the search engine and I don't know how to change this.
header:
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
<meta name="description">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo.svg">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
<title>----------</title>
<script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.60353bf7.js"></script>
<link href="/static/css/main.f855e6bc.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>:is([id*='google_ads_iframe'],[id*='taboola-'],.taboolaHeight,.taboola-placeholder,#credential_picker_container,#credentials-picker-container,#credential_picker_iframe,[id*='google-one-tap-iframe'],#google-one-tap-popup-container,.google-one-tap-modal-div,#amp_floatingAdDiv,#ez-content-blocker-container) {display:none!important;min-height:0!important;height:0!important;}</style>
<style data-emotion="css" data-s=""></style>
</head>

manifest:
{
  "short_name": "---------",
  "name": "-----------",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}

I have tried to change the icon several times but nothing has helped.

This line : , why not replace that file with the icon you would rather see?  Do you have access to the files where you could just switch that .ico file out with the one you want?

You should just replace the favicon.ico with the one you want to use.
Make sure you replace favicon.ico with the file you are using.
This article explains it well.


In your code editor, find the favicon file in the public folder of your React app… it’s called, ‘favicon.ico’:

Delete the favicon file: right click on ‘favicon.ico’, then click ‘Delete’.

Find a new favicon to replace the default React favicon. Google Image search for an icon/emoji and save the image you like somewhere
on your computer. It’s best to find an image that’s in .png format and
has a transparent background. For this ‘To-Do List’ example, I
searched for a green checkmark icon, and saved it to my desktop.

Drag and drop the saved image into the public folder of your code editor:

Right click on the image file you just added, then click ‘Rename’, and replace the entire file name (including .png extension) with
‘favicon.ico’:

Save your changes in your code editor, refresh the browser tab, and you should see the new favicon...




Yes, I also see the favicon in the tabbar, but it does not appear when you search for the page in the google search then the old favicon still appears there
